# how can insert multiple record using

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a small project **Django Rest Framework**, I already create add contact function as you can see in my create function.   now I'm working on bulk import, but when I submit my data as a **list** not as a **dict** I get an error message :

```
{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."]}
```

this is my code to add a contact,

```
class ContactView(ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        serializeObject = ContactSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializeObject.is_valid():
            serializeObject.save()
            contactObject = Contact.objects.all()
            contactSerializer = ContactSerializer(contactObject, many=True)
            return Response(contactSerializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializeObject.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Now i would like to create another function, for bulk create, since i have a list

This is my header data structure :

```
[{"Greeting":"amine","first_name":"alain","last_name":"amine","title":"ricardo","language":"ab@xyz.com","email":43822510594,"phone_1":43822510594,"phone_2":"not yet","mobile":43822510594,"fax":"not yet","internal_id":"xname"},{"Greeting":"bill","first_name":"microsoft","last_name":"bill","title":"microsoft","language":"bill@microsoft.com","email":652565455,"phone_1":652565455,"phone_2":"new york","mobile":652565455,"fax":"new york","internal_id":"microsoft"},{"Greeting":"john","first_name":"Yoyo","last_name":"Ruth","title":"xnameagain","language":"rh@xyz.com","email":5465559852,"phone_1":5465559852,"phone_2":"Vancouver","mobile":5465559852,"fax":"Vancouver","internal_id":"yname"}]
```

This is my serializer:

```
class ContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = "__all__"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i bulk create in django rest serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33826742/how-can-i-bulk-create-in-django-rest-serializer)

Comment: @Tiki   must i extend ModelSerializer ?

Comment: No, but maybe you should avoid using a serializer in this create method and iterate the list and for each dict validate/create objects.

Comment: @Tiki  example is little complicated :) ,  can you give me an example based on my code please

Comment: @Tiki should i create a new serializer ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the Solution on https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dealing-with-multiple-objects

all what i have to do is to add many=True to create multiple object

```
serializeObject = ContactSerializer(data = request.data, many=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create method should look like this:

```py
class ContactView(ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer

    def create(self, request):
        valid_objects = []
        for data in request.data:
            serializeObject = ContactSerializer(data=data)
            if serializeObject.is_valid():
                valid_objects.append(serializeObject)
            else:
                return Response(serializeObject.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        for obj in valid_objects:
            obj.save()
        contactObject = Contact.objects.all()
        contactSerializer = ContactSerializer(contactObject, many=True)
        return Response(contactSerializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

#### Advise

- They may not be the best practices but it works.

Comment: i'm getting "first_name":["This field is required."]   since is not empty

Comment: May you post the data received and the serializer class ContactSerializer?

Comment: can you double check please :)

Comment: So you are providing the **first_name** in all the dictionaries and the error is displayed?

Comment: can you explain to me what it means    (**data, author=author)     here in the example :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61920674/how-to-override-post-method-for-bulk-adding-django-rest-framework

Comment: Do all dict keys match the field names in the model? I tried the code with a small model and it works correctly.

Comment: I think you alright,   can you please see the link, and explain to me  the mapping, how can i use the same code please :)    link

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21809162/11972800) clearly explains what **data does.

Comment: how can i implement this function please :)   ?   also i will vote your answer :)

Comment: what should i do instead of author = author